# Java Sort List of ArrayList of difference length by its size in asc or desc

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
List<ArrayList<Integer>> tree = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();`
tree.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(4,5,6)));`
tree.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2,3)));
tree.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1)));       
tree.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2, 3)));
tree.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2)));
tree.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(5)));
tree.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(5,6)));
System.out.println(tree);
```

---

It return the result:

```
[[4, 5, 6], [2, 3], [1], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [5], [5, 6]]
```

I want to sort it in asc or desc based on value of digit position and its length and want the result: 
* asc:  `[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [5], [5, 6]` 
* desc: `[5, 6], [5], [4, 5, 6], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1]`

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried to do it yourself? can you show the code?

Comment: Check how to use `Collections.sort` and [edit] the question with the problem you get at that point.

Comment: I am new to Comparator!
I just tested it.
`tree.forEach(Collections::sort);`
`Collections.sort(tree, (l1, l2) -> l1.get(0).compareTo(l2.get(0)));`

Comment: Then follow a guide on how to use and write a comparator first. It is not complicated, but  you can't expect us to start from scratch

Comment: You have the idea to place the many number of element of the list before or after such as desc:  [5, 6], [5], [4, 5, 6]?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this code? **I haven't test it yet!**
 It might sort it reversed in some cases, but this is the logic you should do.

```
List<ArrayList<Integer>> tree = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        tree.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(4,5,6)));
        tree.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2,3)));
        tree.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1)));       
        tree.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2, 3)));
        tree.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2)));
        tree.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(5)));
        tree.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(5,6)));
        System.out.println(tree);
        Collections.sort(tree, new Comparator<ArrayList<Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ArrayList<Integer> o1, ArrayList<Integer> o2) {
                int minSize = Math.min(o1.size(), o2.size());
                for(int i =0 ; i< minSize;i ++) {
                    //to compare element in inner list
                    if(o1.get(i).compareTo(o2.get(i)) != 0){
                        return o1.get(i).compareTo(o2.get(i));
                    }
                }
                //if all elements are the same to same index, return o2 as smaller list
                if(o1.size() > o2.size()) {
                    return 1;
                }else{
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank You. The code worked well. How can you change direction to descending?

Comment: By multiplying return values with -1 will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Comparator` from Java 8, first compare the elements of the list, then the size:

```
tree.sort(Comparator.comparing((List<Integer> list) -> list.stream()
                            .map(a -> Integer.toString(a))
                            .collect(Collectors.joining()))
                     .thenComparing(List::size));
```

For reversed sorting, just add the `.reversed()` at the end of comparator:

```
tree.sort(Comparator.comparing((List<Integer> list) -> list.stream()
                            .map(a -> Integer.toString(a))
                            .collect(Collectors.joining()))
                        .thenComparing(List::size).reversed());
```

Comment: @YSchidu Luca
Yes it worked perfect for ascending. How about descending?

Comment: @YSchidu Luca
Yes it worked perfect for ascending. How about descending?
How to use .reverseOrder()?

Comment: Perfect!
Thank you so much!

Comment: Wow, this answer should be mark as accepted. Even I run this and it working very well. Even the solution given @Abdullah is working. 

PS: I am still trying to figure it out how this code working :P

Comment: @SchiduLuca can you explain your logic what is happening while comparing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @James - read the article http://www.baeldung.com/java-8-comparator-comparing . There's described everything (Comparator, reversed, thenComparing). It's just using the Comparator from java 8, nothing fancy.

Comment: @SchiduLuca Sorry anyway, do you have idea of?
desc: `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]; [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]; [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]; [2, 3, 4, 5]; [1, 4, 5]; [1, 2, 3]; [4, 5]; [1, 3]; [5]; [3]; [1]`
Thank You!